# How to type hint arguments of factory method, where the managed instances are from generic class with additional constructor args

Tags: python, factory, type-hinting

Consider the following case where we have a Manager which manages instances of certain classes. These classes must be a subclass of a given class but can be user-defined (i.e. are a generic).

Since the Manager class has ownership of the instances, the question is how to correctly type-hint the situation as the to be managed Instance class may have user defined constructor.

Example:

```
class Base:
    """Base class for all instances"""
    def __init__(self, base_arg1: int, base_arg2: float):
        pass


InstanceType = TypeVar('InstanceType', bounds=Base)  # must be subclass of Base

class Manager(Generic[InstanceType]):
    """The manager class. Is a factory of Instances, creates and owns them. However instances
    may have custom extra arguments in their constructor. How to type-hint them correctly?"""
    def __init__(self, instance_class: Type[InstanceType]):
        self.factory = instance_class
        pass
   
    def new_instance(self, ??? )  # how to type hint the extra args of the constructor of InstanceType (without the base_args from Base.__init__)?
        self.factory( ???, base_arg1=123, base_arg2=4.56 )
        pass

class Instance(Base):
    def __init__(self, extra_arg: bool, base_arg1: int, base_arg2: float): # note this has extra_arg: bool
        pass


instance_manager = Manager(Instance)  # note  this will be correctly inferred as Manager[Instance]

instance_manager.new_instance(extra_arg=True)  # How can this be correctly type-checked ??
```

I was thinking along the lines of using a Callable in the manager constructor, to capture the function arguments. But then I am unsure how to proceed.

```
class Manager(Generic[InstanceType]):
    def __init__(self, instance_class: Callable[ [???], InstanceType]):   # use Callable instead of Type
        pass
```

This leaves the questions:

1. how to capture the arguments of the Callable and use these in the definition of 'new_instance' (but without(!) the base_args)
2. how to enforce that the arguments contain the arguments of the Base class (i.e. base_arg1, and base_arg2).

For me 1. is most important, I could live without 2.

Comment: Can you live with one more restriction? New parameters can go only after `Base.__init__` parameters, otherwise your desire is not expressible in current typing system. If it's ok for you, then consider something like [this](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=4f95771852b42e57b83a94c25d20d06f).

Comment: @STerliakov Yes this restriction is definitely acceptable. Ideally we would only have kwargs (and then order does not matter), but yes what you propose is definitely a good solution. If you post an answer I will accept it.